# Websphere MQ and C# message type URI and format

Tags: java, c#, uri, ibm-mq

I'm trying to send a message from my c# application to a Java application communicating through the Websphere MQ using the amqmdnet library. I'm able to successfully connect to the MQ server and send the message to the Java application.

The messages received in the Java application are missing 2 properties

1. "messagetypeuri", "URI:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx" and
2. "format", "xml"

How do I set these parameters on my c# code.

```
queueMessage = new MQMessage();
queueMessage.CorrelationId = corrID;
queueMessage.CharacterSet = 1208;
queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
byte[] utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
string msg = BitConverter.ToString(utf8String);
queueMessage.WriteBytes(utf8String);
queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I used MQ v8 .NET API and the following code to put message to a queue and I am able retrieve message properties using MQ JMS application.

```
        swMsg.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        swMsg.CharacterSet = 1208;
        swMsg.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;
        swMsg.WriteUTF(strMsg);
        swMsg.SetStringProperty("MessageTypeURI", "URI:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx");
        swQueue.Put(swMsg);
```

Can you post your code?